# Windows driver signing: How to get an Azure ID

Tags: windows, azure, driver, code-signing

We develop Windows device drivers. To get them signed by Microsoft we need an EV certificate. Up until a few weeks ago, I could log in with my Microsoft account and submit a new driver for attestation signing.

A few weeks ago, something was changed.  Now I need an Azure ID.  Sure, I applied for one and in that process I have to use a new email address, something like user@subdomian.onmicrosoft.com.  I got that as well.  Now, to continue the process I have to sign, with my EV certificate, some dummy file from Microsoft (SignableFile.bin) and upload it again.

When I do that, they tell me that I used that certificate already for some other account.  Yeah, sure!  I used it a long time with my old account, but that doesn't seem to work any more.

Question: how can I remove the old account or the link between it and the certificate?  Or, how can I use the old account "as Azure ID", if that makes any sense.  There is no help button or anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, here:

It reads "What I finally figure out was that under my user name (top right), was a new menu item with the name of my company on it (previously it just had "Sign out" and "Account settings"). Once I clicked on this menu item, it took me to the page where I could access the HARDWARE menu and submit drivers."

And that did the trick.  It has nothing to do with Azure ID. :)